# firefox doesn't load external fonts

Tags: html, css, apache, firefox

i read this article about firefox and the external fonts:
http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/07/fixing-firefox-font-face-cross-domain_25.html

it says that i should put some code into my apatche config:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

i've got to the path: `apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf` and put those lines but in firebug, the response headers didn't changed at all.

i want to mention that the article said something about loading the headers module if it's not loaded

any idea to load the headers module in the `httpd.conf` file, or to make the firefox accept external fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need this somewhere in your Apache config:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

If you're on Windows, it would probably be `mod_headers.dll`, or something slightly different. You should probably look at other `LoadModule` statements in your `httpd.conf` to figure out the appropriate version.

Answer (score 1):

I already had the same problem. I was adviced to generate my web fonts with a tool like [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). Upload your font's files and download back a compatible pack. Include the css in your HTML page in addition to yours. And it seems to work since I do like this. I hope it will be the same for you.